# Which one is the latest stable version of phonegap?

Tags: cordova

Wikipedia shows 4.2.0 is latest version. 
Phonegap website shows 2.9.1 version for download. It doesn't provide xml folder and config.xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Wikipedia is right. And what you might have seen on Phonegap's website is the list of Archived versions, which is not what you want. If you already have phonegap installed, you can find which version you've got in your terminal/cmd:

```
phonegap -v
```

To update Phonegap:

```
npm update -g phonegap
```

And if you are on a Linux machine you might have to add `sudo` to the command:

```
sudo npm update -g phonegap
```